# Redirect Homepage on Expression Engine Site

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, expressionengine

due to internal politics with a project I need to redirect only the homepage of a site built in Expression Engine to a different url. I want to be able to access the rest of the site to show people but just that when it goes to the homepage it redirects you.

I tried both .htaccess file and a meta refresh on the homepage.  The htaccess redirected every page since /index.php is in every url, and by just doing a meta refresh on the homepage, even at a refresh of 0 it still takes a second before it switches.

Anyone know a way around this?
Anyone know how to do this with .htaccess ?

Comment: Does `Expression Engine` have a .htaccess already? If yes then post it's content here.

Comment: nope, never had an htaccess file in expressionengine

Comment: And are you sure mod_rewrite and that particular .htaccess is enabled and working?

Comment: How would I check to see if it was?  If did a regular 301 redirect on index.php it works, but thats not the results I want

Comment: ok good that means `mod_rewrite` is working fine. I have zero knowledge of `expressionengine` so just guessing things here. Do you have online reference to it that I can read and understand better.

Comment: It should be standard, php based CMS, index.php?/ part of every url/...this is a link to the docs - http://ee1docs.com/  one would think that it should be a standrd redirect, but alas....

Comment: Can you please give us a sample URL that should redirect and another sample URL that should not redirect?

Comment: Sure, it should redirect from mywebsite.com or mywebsite.com/index.php but it should not redirect from mywebsite.com/index.php?/about

Comment: So if you make a `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` and place `RewritEngine On RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L,R]` does `http://domain.com/foo` get redirected to `http://domain.com/bar`?

Comment: right now I have an .htaccess file that says RewriteRule ^$ http://www.newwebsite.com/newlink/[L,R]  and its doing nothing.  the homepage loads and the url just adds the /index.php

Answer (score 0):

Create a new template group, make its index "home" using the ee group prefs. Have that page write a header to do a 302 redirect.  Or turn on php and call redirect.

Comment: That was an initial idea of mine (something similar) but if I do that it will come to the site first and then only redirect after a second...I want it to be an automatic redirect without loading the old site first

Comment: Don't know what "automatic redirect" means to you, but this method should be very fast.  No, it will not be as fast as doing it in .htaccess but the difference will probably not be noticeable.  In both cases a http header redirect is being returned by the server.